# How to install bower in Linux Fedora?

Tags: linux, bower, fedora

I tried using this following command script:

1. npm install -g bower
2. sudo npm install -g bower

Error display:

```
sudo npm install -g bower

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

How old is your npm version?
If it is less than 2.1, try installing latest npm with the command,

```
sudo sh -c 'curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh' #install npm 2.1 using the cmd ----
```

and then do,

```
npm install bower -g
```